# Web navigation using WebView 2 in Hololens 2 + Unity (MRTK2)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, webview2, mrtk

I am trying out WebView2 Preview on HoloLens 2 using Unity 2022 and MRTK 2.8.

Loading web pages works great, but I am not able to click on web's buttons, do scroll, etc.

I have found [this section of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/hololens2#input) which seems to point to web navigation, but I am not able to get it working.

This is my current code:

```cs
private IWebView _webView;

private void Start()
{
    GetComponentInChildren<WebView>().GetWebViewWhenReady(webView =>
    {
        _webView = webView;
    });
}

public void OnPointerDown(MixedRealityPointerEventData eventData)
{
    IWithMouseEvents mouseEventsWebView = _webView as IWithMouseEvents;

    var hitCoord = ConvertToWebViewSpace(eventData.Pointer.Position.x, eventData.Pointer.Position.y);
    
    WebViewMouseEventData mouseEvent = new()
    {
        X = hitCoord.x,
        Y = hitCoord.y,
        Type = WebViewMouseEventData.EventType.MouseDown,
        Button = WebViewMouseEventData.MouseButton.ButtonLeft,
        TertiaryAxisDeviceType = WebViewMouseEventData.TertiaryAxisDevice.PointingDevice
    };
   
    mouseEventsWebView.MouseEvent(mouseEvent);
}

private Vector2Int ConvertToWebViewSpace(float xPos, float yPos)
{    
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(GetComponent<RectTransform>(), new Vector2(xPos, yPos), Camera.main, out Vector2 localPoint);
    
    return Vector2Int.RoundToInt(localPoint);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same issue. Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: To perform a click action, you will need to send a LeftButtonDown event and then a LeftButtonUp event.